# Create alias to change directory and list contents

Tags: bash

I want to change the behavior of the cd command so that it changes to a directory and lists the files in that directory, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
 % alias cd='cd $@; ls'
```

It lists the files of the directory as if it had changed directory but when it is done executing it leaves me in the same directory.

Comment: It's really crazy (IHMO) to override one of the key cmds in all of unix file-system navigation. At least use CD, or whynot some other 2 letter abberviation (LS)?. Good luck.

Comment: You aren't overriding it. You are telling `bash` to run `cd ... && ls`  when you type in `cd` into your prompt.

Comment: as long as you don't alias unalias you can easily revert...

Comment: Or just re-open your Terminal emulator ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make cd automatically ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20396/make-cd-automatically-ls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alias to CD in a directory and call a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366009/alias-to-cd-in-a-directory-and-call-a-command)

Comment: It looks like most, if not all, of the applicable answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366009/alias-to-cd-in-a-directory-and-call-a-command would *also* leave the current shell in the current directory.

Comment: my cd is a function too and it inserts $(pwd) in a sqlite3 database so I can audit/select and even cd in the previous directory, plus alert me if I'm inside a git repo :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this in by `.bashrc`:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

---

To disable it, you could try overriding it inside of your script:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it. There's no way you can do this with an alias.

Comment: I was wondering, I have to sometimes run some scripts that use cd.. now I would like to disable it for those. How could I remove this functionality on those scripts

Comment: Override it. See my comment.

Comment: @Flethuseo: You remove a shell function with the `unset` command: `unset cd` in your case.

Comment: Its very important that if you do this that you put it in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile or .profile. .bashrc is only meant to be read when you have an interactive shell and thus your override won't get used by scripts that use 'cd'. Otherwise, you're probably going to break something.

Comment: I dont' need to use a function name of cd, but with cdd, but I am getting syntax error `line 16: syntax error near unexpected token 'builtin' `. The full code is ```function cdd{ builtin cd "$@" && ls  } ```