# I can not create alias to change directory and list contents

Tags: bash

I know that exists [a previous question about this subject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24921/create-alias-to-change-directory-and-list-contents/562593#562593). But a moderator has delete my question in these thread, for this reason I ask here the same.

In my *.bashrc* I try with:

```bsh
alias cl='$HOME/.cFolder.sh'
```

The content of `.cFolder.sh` is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cFolder() {
    cd $1 && pwd && ls;
}

cFolder $1
```

When I execute my new alias I get this:

```
 jonathan ~ $ cl Documentos/myScripts/
/home/jonathan/Documentos/myScripts

arranque-fallido.log      firstInstall.sh    makeAllPacks.sh          ORIGINAL-installPegaso.sh  restoreBackup.sh  startInitialConfig.sh
configure-usb-install.sh  fixDatabase.sh     makeInstallationPack.sh  README.md          restoreData.sh    testZenity.sh
downloadDebs.sh       installAppPack.sh  myScripts-Functions.sh   recoverSystem.sh       setNetwork.sh     updateWeb.sh
 jonathan ~ $
```

The list of files is correct. But it doesn't change my actual folder. The .cFolder.sh script runs in his own space.

The option:

```bsh
alias cl='cFolder() { cd $1 && pwd && ls; }'
```

doesn't work for me. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt creates an alias to run a shell script that changes directory. Only, as explained in many places, you cannot change your current shell's directory from a subshell. So this doesn't work.

The second attempt creates an alias that defines a function. It doesn't run it, so this almost certainly isn't what you want.

Remove the aliases you've created, and put this into your `.bashrc`

```
cFolder() { cd "$1" || return; pwd; ls; }
```

The next time you start a shell you will have a new "command" called `cFolder`. No need for an alias. No need for a separate script.

Comment: Thanks! I was using this solution, but I don't understand why I can't use the 'alias' option and other people can.

Comment: Like I said, your alias simply defined a function.

Comment: Oh, and I don't see any successful use of an alias to do what you want. Due to the way aliases interpolate arguments (i.e. they don't), I'd be inclined to say it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thanks very much for your help.