# Change Directory and List Files

Tags: shell, utilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make cd automatically ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20396/make-cd-automatically-ls)

I think that it would be very useful to have a unix utility that combines 'cd' and 'ls' so that when you change your directory, it automatically lists the files in that directory.  I have tried to do this using shell scripts, and C programs and a combination of the two, but nothing seems to work, because any 'cd' or 'chdir()' call in a shell script/ c program only changes the directory for that instance (not for the shell).

The psudocode would look like (if it was only this simple!):

```
cd $1
ls
```

If anyone has any ideas of how to implement this I would really appreciate it!

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `.bashrc`:

```
cl() { cd "$1" && ls -al; }
```

you would use cl instead of cd to change directory and then ls -al