# -bash: /bin/cd: No such file or directory - automatically execute ls after cd

Tags: linux, alias, cd-command

I accidentially destroyed my `cd` command.

I tried to automatically execute `ls` after `cd` is called.

I found a post saying that I have to execute `alias cd='/bin/cd && /bin/ls'`, but now I get `-bash: /bin/cd: No such file or directory` and can't change directoy anymore.

Comment: There is no `/bin/cd`; `cd` is a shell built-in.

Comment: Enjoy https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354123/ and what it hyperlinks to M. Dalton.  (-:

Comment: A POSIX compliant platform has a `/bin/cd`, but that only exists for formal reasons and is not usable for anything.

Comment: Wow `/bin/cd` must be the most useless command.

Comment: cd isn't a file on disk, It's a shell built-in command:`type cd`

Comment: @PersianGulf: You should use `-a`. One example: MacOS `type -a cd` outputs "cd is a shell builtin" and "cd is /usr/bin/cd". See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/382)

Comment: [Why is cd not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/44425)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I use without `-a` on Debian and `bash` shell.

Comment: @PersianGulf: If you use `-a` (even on Debian and Bash), it will tell you _all_ the ways the argument is defined (aliases, builtins, and functions and executable files - including instances in multiple parts of the `PATH`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your system (like many Unix systems) does not have an external `cd` command (at least not at that path). Even if it had one, the `ls` would give you the directory listing of the original directory.  An external command can never change directory for the calling process (your shell)<sup>1</sup>.

Remove the alias from the environment with `unalias cd` (and also remove its definition from any shell initialization files that you may have added it to).

With a shell function, you can get it to work as `cd` ordinarily does, with an extra invocation of `ls` at the end if the `cd` succeeded:

```
cd () {
    command cd "$@" && ls -lah
}
```

or,

```
cd () { command cd "$@" && ls -lah; }
```

This would call the `cd` command built into your shell with the same command line arguments that you gave the function.  If the change of directory was successful, the `ls` would run.

The `command` command stops the shell from executing the function recursively.

The function definition (as written above) would go into your shell's startup file.  With `bash`, this might be `~/.bashrc`.  The function definition would then be active in the *next new interactive shell session*.  If you want it to be active *now*, then execute the function definition as-is at the interactive shell prompt, which will define it within your current interactive session.

---

<sup>1</sup> On systems where `cd` is available as an external command, this command also does not change directory for the calling process. The only real use for such a command is to provide POSIX compliance and for acting as a test of whether changing directory to a particular one *would be possible*.

Comment: Where do I have to put the function?

Comment: @Black You may put it wherever you would have put the `alias` definition.  In a `bash` shell, that would probably be in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I added the function to `~/.bashrc` but it does not work. `ls -lah` is not executed at all.

Comment: @Black No, you add it exactly the way I wrote it. Then it will be active in any _new_ shell session.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work at all. I am using Linux 4.4

Comment: @Black If you still have your `cd` alias, then `unalias cd` (and delete that alias definition from `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Note that POSIXly, you'd use `cd() { command cd "$@" && ls -lah; }`, though that wouldn't work with `zsh` except in `sh` emulation.  Not all shells have a `builtin` builtin. In ksh93, it does something different.

Comment: @Black Linux 4.4 is not an OS and obviously not a shell, so it can't run any commands

Comment: @phuclv, I see, I am using SUSE Linux

Comment: I had to restart my shell, now your solution works! :)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve it by removing the alias again with `unalias cd`

Comment: If you remove the stuck-out text, then this is the only answer that answers the question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Note there's no question in the question. We could only guess what the implicit question is. In this situation "why?" is as good as "how to revert?"

Answer (score 5):

That happened because:

```
$ type cd

cd is a shell builtin
```